# How to nest documents into other documents

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm working on a rest API app where I have a lot of different methods that do totally different things. I, therefore, decided that it would be a good idea to structurize my database into different folders, each folders storing different collections. I'm therefore looking to design a folder-like structure in my database to organize this and figured nesting documents into others would be the way to go.
How can I do this? (I'm using express as my API framework for reference)

Answer (score 2):

You should use mixed types and ObjectId types to design your schemas to create sub-doc and store references to other collections.

Please refer:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Hope this helps. If you give a more specific use case(description), will try to help you design your schema.

Comment: I'm basically trying to create folders like you would do in windows. Is something like this possible in mongoose?

Comment: Yes it is possible, Like you have address schema with some fields and you can have another user schema which has some attributes, one of the attribute can be of type address.